# How do I create a hook for React Router Dom without any third party libraries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

**I need a hook for React Router whereby everytime a user navigates to page analytic data is sent to our server.**

---

This needs to be on every page so I want to abstract this network call away from the developer so it all happends in the background. I don't want developers to have to manually put an analytic event on every Route they create. I need some kind of middleware for react router.

We are currently using the `react-router-dom` library. I looked through the source code but I could not find any methods to hook into events; or any notion of events at all.

I see their are [react-router-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hook) but it looks like that package depends on the `react-router` package, which we don't use. And honestly I am not thrilled about introducing a new external library just for what should be simple behavior.

I suppose I could always just import the native `Route` object from `react-router-dom` and create a wrapper for it which would allow me to implement my own behavior. I would prefer not to extend a third party library unless it was absolutely necessary though.

How do I create a hook for React Router Dom without any third party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapper is one option, you named it.

**However, I would go for a hook in my top (`<Application />`) component to detect route changes and send events**.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.location !== nextProps.location) {
    sendEvent(); // location has changed, do your work
  }
}
```

*PS. Depending on your setup, you might need to wrap in [withRouter](http://%20reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to make it aware of location changes.*

Comment: The top `Application` component does not detect route changes in my application. I can't get `componentWillReceiveProps` to trigger when route changes occur.

Comment: wrap in withRouter https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter to be aware of location changes